# Angular Enable/Disable Save button if toggles are changed from their loaded state

Tags: angular

I have a dropdown of multiple mat-slide toggle in Angular. I also have a SAVE button which is hidden. How do I show the save button only if any changes are made on the page. Like if  multiple toggles states are changes then it should show save button but if states are changed and reverted back then it should disable save button.

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: create property for this object 'isModified: boolean'

when any toggle is changed/clicked add callback (changed)="setModified()"

then in setModified() { this.isModified = true; }

and in button add [hidden]="isModified"

or you can add any css class which hides button

Comment: There are many answers to this question. Are you using two way data binding, template driven forms, reactive forms, etc.  If you can provide your code then this will encourage answers. A working example of where you are at on https://stackblitz.com/ will also really help showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save a copy of the init values ​​before the user changes (before "dirty") and every time something changes you need to check if it is the same.

For example, if you are using reactive forms:

```
this.isSaveHidden = true; 
this.initialFormValue = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
   this.isSaveHidden = JSON.stringify(value) === this.initialFormValue;
})
```

Comment: It's better to do `this.initialFormValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form.value));` and then in the comparison just compare the values. This way you only convert twice instead of each time you want to compare and you don't lose the integrity of the values.